# Looking for SMTP server

Tags: smtp, email

My site is hosted at Mediatemple but the IP address mail is being sent from is blacklisted so Hotmail messages are not delivered. Therefor I would like to use another SMTP server. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contact your hosting provider and complain. Often with web hosting, a company will put 100 domains on 1 IP address (not unusual). If that IP address gets on [spamhaus.org](http://www.spamhaus.org/) blacklist then you're stuck.

Complain. Get them to give you your own IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Not programming related. But use your ISP's smtp server

Answer (score 0):

indeed complain because if you run a legal bisnuis (witch i gues you are) you have the right to send mail from you hosting trought php (or other forms)